# Minimum cutset matrix from adjacency matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

[image]

Example about cuts: {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}} are the minimum cuts of the left while {{a,b,c},{a,b,f},{a,e,f},{d,b,c},{d,e,c},{d,e,f}} are the minimum cuts of the right. For example, the {a,b,c,d,e,f} in left and right is a cut but it is not minimum. And the adjacency matrix of the digraphs in the below picture and in CSV file with click [here](http://pastebin.com/WPbAFFse).

[image]

*Suppose you have the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph $G$. How can you calculate the cutset matrix $C$ of $G$ with $A$?*

Comment: Are you trying to determine the edge-connectivity of the graph? Do you want it to give an example cut, or _all_ such cuts?

Comment: @JustinBenfield Minimum cuts, two examples added with adjacency matrices shown and their minimum cuts demonstrated. Now the goal is to find out what are their minimum cuts and other graphs given their adjacency matrix.

Comment: I think you can find what you want with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions for algorithms**

1. Ford-Fulkerson algorithm (Justin suggesting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm))
2. *"algorithms computing cocircuits of matroids in general (or for regular matroids, or for graphical matroids) is a good place to start."* (Aaron suggesting matrdoids [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_efficient_algorithm_to_get_cut-set_matrix_from_adjacency_matrix))